# Accelerate 2d Drawing

Tags: qt, opengl, 2d, plot

I'm triying to make a 2D real-time plot. I've tried with modifying the osciloscope example of qwt, tried to use QGraphicsView, and QPainter to reach high framerate drawing. I'm using 8 channels to plot data wich is arriving from a rs232 port. I take a sample every 10 ms.
Maybe i've used the QPainter in a wrong way, but i couldn't draw very fast. With the qwt example, in wich doesn't update the whole screen the drawing speed was good, especially in X11 with Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent and Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen.

Now i'm subclassing the QGLWidget, and i'm reaching a acceptable speed. But i'm wondering if i could improve it.

Every time I recived a new point i stored it, and the call updateGL();
In this case i recived only the y coordinate, buth i'm going to recive the whole pair.

```
void Plot::addPoint(int y)
{
   points[t].x=t;
   points[t].y=y;
   t++;
   updateGL();
}
```

In DrawGL() i check if the line reach the end of the screen, if is True i erase the screen
if not, i draw only the the new part of the line.

```
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i( points[t-1].x, points[t-1].y);
    glVertex2i( points[t-2].x, points[t-2].y);
 glEnd();
```

I've disabled the Dithering and multisampling, and i'm using flat shades.
i'm using an ortographic projection.

is there some way to draw faster? maybe using opengl for off-screen drawing and the showing the corresponding pixmap?
is the a project similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex buffer objects (and perhaps display lists) would help this. Basically you need a way of reducing the number of GL calls you make, and it'll get fast.

Comment: i've just tried using vertex array and it's a bit faster.
Now i'm going to take a look to display lists, and  VBO (it's kind of a complex thing, isn't it? )

Comment: Yeah, they're not quite as simple as what you've got now.

Also, it occurs to me that you should probably just treat your points array as a circular buffer, and redraw the whole thing every time DrawGL is invoked. That'll keep it as simple as possible, and should look identical. (probably even better; you'll get less flickering on the right hand side of the screen.)

Comment: I've made an attempt to clear the whole scene and redrawing all the scene in every drawGl, but it's turn really slow. But, i don't know, i'm redrawing 8 widgets, with at least 800 point each one. The Dublebuffering make it worst. I'm, for sure, doing something wrong. With a SingleBuffer and drawing only the last part of the curve I get and semi-acecptable speed :S
maybe making 1 widget with 8 lines?